# Comic-book style for Keynote?

Tags: fonts, iwork-keynote

I've got a couple of slides that I would like to present with comic-book style fonts and formatting (just the words, not pictures).

Any good template/font resources for this?

Comment: You don't like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_Sans ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Anime Ace](http://www.dafont.com/anim-ace.font) is a great comic-style font. Also, [Badaboom](http://www.dafont.com/badaboom-bb.font) for sound effects (if you need that for some reason :P).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [downloadable TrueType Font](http://www.dafont.com/Comic-Book.font) file of the classic comic book font. Note that comic books never use lowercase letters, just uppercase letters that are little smaller.

Here are [some instructions](http://www.dafont.com/faq.php#mac) on how to install the font after you download it.

Comment: Pick up any Marvel comic today or for the last ten years, they use lowercase a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[Blambot Comic Fonts by Nate Piekos](http://www.blambot.com/fonts.shtml) features nothing but fonts for comics and has been [used in various titles](http://www.comics.org/search.lasso?query=blambot&type=letters&sort=alpha&Submit=Search).

The fonts are broken down into [two licenses](http://www.blambot.com/license.shtml):

> - **Free fonts** are for any independent comics use, or non-commercial use (includes non-profit)
> - **Pay fonts** have extra characters and features. For professional, commercial uses

A majority of the fonts are uppercase only. But if you've ever read a Marvel comic in the last decade you'll see some that have lowercase as well.

Comment: If you have the budget for it, checkout the powerhouse that is http://Comicraft.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few fonts available at 1001fonts.com and a few other similar sites that have a comic book feel to them.

As far as templates, there are some community resources around that offer presentation templates that have been created by users. Do a web search for "Keynote Themes" or "Presentation Themes" and you'll find quite a few options to pick from.

If you want a comic book look though, [Comic Life](http://plasq.com/comiclife/) may be something to look into if you are planning on doing a comic book style regularly.

Answer (score 0):

[some comic book fonts](http://www.comicbookfonts.com/index.html?sid=0001Rdax9NtOmNgigQ0b1H9)